# How do I update a menu bar in a calling template

Tags: jsf, primefaces

As an exercise I want to have a menu bar which is disabled until the user logs in. When he logs in I want to call something which will trigger an update. The menu bar is in the `master.xhtml` template file

```
<h:form >
  <p:menubar id="masterMenuBar">
  <p:menuitem disabled="#{backing.disableMenu}" value="List users" />
  </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

As part of the login I have code to refresh the form

```
public void refreshForm() {
  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
  context.update("form1"); 
  context.update("masterMenuBar");
}
```

I tried my luck with calling a context update to my defined label of `masterMenuBar` but the `RequestContext` apparently doesn't include my calling template form (which sounds reasonable enough).

Is there some other context I can call which will include a context update to my menu bar? Perhaps I am on the wrong path, and there is a better way to achieve the same thing?

I did notice that even resizing the browser wasn't reason enough to call again to my `backing.disableMenu` bean. Apparently I need something fairly strong to cause it to reach my bean a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the absolute client ID, not the relative client ID. If you rightclick and view source in browser, then you'll see that the `masterMenuBar` element has the (autogenerated) ID of its form prefixed.

You need to give the form where the menu is sitting in a fixed ID

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <p:menubar id="masterMenuBar">
        ...
```

and pass the absolute client ID instead.

```
context.update("menuForm:masterMenuBar");
```

---

**Update**: sorry, it shouldn't start with `:` in contrary to the `update` attribute of `<p:commandButton>`.

Comment: Oops I managed to confuse you. There are TWO forms, one in the master template and the other in the welcome.xhtml file. The welecome one does have an id="form1". However, if I take your idea maybe what I need to do is context.update(":masterMenuBar"). I'll try that.

Comment: That would also not work if it's inside a form. You need to pass its absolute client ID which would be `:form1:masterMenuBar`. Check generated HTML output to see it. By the way it really doesn't matter how many templates/includes you use, there's after all only one `UIViewRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've been trying everything I can think of but I can't get it to hit my breakpoint more than once. I thought maybe it wouldn't like to use <p:menubar id="masterMenuBar">, so I moved the id= up one line to the form. That didn't make any difference. I tried combinations of :masterMenuBar, master:masterMenuBar and :master:masterMenuBar and nothing works. It still hits the breakpoint just once.

Comment: Maybe the real problem is I can't do an update of one form from inside another. My submit button is inside the form id=form1, within welcome.xhtml. My menu commands are inside another form within master.xhtml. If this is a problem, what is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, the `RequestContext#update()` should not take the ID prefixed with `:` in contrary to the `update` attribute of for example `<p:commandButton>`. It should take absolute IDs without prefix. I updated the answer.

Comment: You are a genius, it worked! I would have never been able to guess the answer without your help.