# can I update the title bar?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671133/how-do-i-update-a-menu-bar-in-a-calling-template) I asked about updating a menu bar. BalusC told me that I need to add the form containing the menu bar.

I would like to extend that question to ask if I can update the text in the title. A template is being used and I fill in the value using

```
    <ui:define name="AreaTitle">
        #{viewBacking.current.firstName}  #{viewBacking.current.surName}
    </ui:define>
```

The template has

```
<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="AreaTitle">Master template</ui:insert></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</h:head>
```

It seems strange to define a form in the header so none is defined. I put a break point in the viewBacking.current so I can see when it uses it. Even if I hit the refresh to redisplay the form, it won't hit the break point again. Only when I go to a different page with different content does it hit the break point again. The for the refresh is

```
public void refreshForm() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    context.update("menuForm:masterMenuBar");
    context.update("AreaTitle");
}
```

This shows the previous solution which BalusC gave me on the masterMenuBar. It could well be that I can't do what I'm asking to do, but I'd like confirmation if that is the case.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't update the title by JSF ajax update simply because `<title>` is not a JSF component. You also can't put HTML or JSF components in `<title>`, this is [illegal](http://validator.w3.org) HTML syntax.

Your best bet is to use JavaScript instead to update the title by assigning it to the `document.title`. You can use `RequestContext#execute()` for this.

```
String fullName = current.getFirstName() + " " + current.getSurName();
context.execute("document.title='" + fullName + "'");
```

Since this seems to be user-controlled data, I would use [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJavaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) to escape it in order to prevent potential [XSS attack holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```
String fullName = current.getFirstName() + " " + current.getSurName();
context.execute("document.title='" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(fullName) + "'");
```

An alternative is to use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:onloadScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript).

```
<o:onloadScript>document.title='#{of:escapeJS(viewBacking.current.firstName)} #{of:escapeJS(viewBacking.current.surName)}'</o:onloadScript>
```

This will be re-executed on every ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of the illegal check of HTML syntax. I tried it and got 62 errors. It picked up all the special input associated with primefaces and marked them all as illegal. With all the false positives it is more difficult to see real problems.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and clearly it worked. I would like a bit more if I may ask. For many pages I would like slightly more than the name, i.e. the name + some sort of suggestion which page he is currently using. To get that I either have to get to my <ui:define name="AreaTitle"> or get the value of what is the current page name.