# Updating <title> text in JavaServer Faces 2 + PrimeFaces 3.3.1

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to periodically update the text of the `<title>` of a page? For example with `<p:poll>`? Or do I need a full page reload for that? I want to display a value from my backing bean.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738839/620338](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738839/620338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using PrimeFaces's [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf):

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("document.title='Number: " + number + "'");
```

I added this code to a method in my backing bean, which gets executed periodically as an effect of a `<p:poll>`.

Thanks for the directions [Matt Handy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620338/matt-handy)!