# Change jsf page title dynamically

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have two tags on my page under - ui:composition

```
1) - ui:define name="title" 
2) - ui:define name="content"
```

Under 'content' I have a form in which I am displaying some page heading like -

```
    h:form id="headingForm"
            <h3>#{Some_Heading_Here}</h3>
```

The content of page is updated on the basis of some condition (on button click,link click etc), Parallely i am updating 'headingForm' with some different text.
So, I am not able to update 'title' content as I am updating 'headingForm' content.
Is this possible what I am doing, If yes then what is the best way to do this.

Comment: There's some ambiguity in the question. When you said "jsf page title", didn't you actually mean the "HTML page title" as in the value of the `<title>` element in the `<head>`?

Comment: Actually on my page I have title component like -                                        "<ui:define name="title">#{some_title}</ui:define>", I need to update it dynamically basis.

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738211/can-i-update-the-title-bar/ Question only assumes PrimeFaces while yours don't, but the technical answer is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

that's so simple .
just like it :

```
 <ui:define name="header">
    <title>#{Some_Heading_Here}</title>
</ui:define>
```

and your template.xhtml changes ( *ui:insert* ) to some thing like it:

```
<h:head>
   <ui:insert name="header">
      <ui:include src="/template/commonContent.xhtml"/>
   </ui:insert>
</h:head>
```